# "What to hell I was holding him up for"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Later the car encountered a similar obstacle at another railroad crossing, this time in Matfield, where a more determined guard planted himself by the tracks and held up a stop sign to block the car from the path of another oncoming train. “[T]hey did not seem to want to stop . . .,” the guard said. “[O]ne of them in the automobile asked me, **‘What to hell I was holding him up for?**’”*

Can you please tell me what the passage in bold in the excerpt could excatly  mean. The phrasal verb "hold sb up" has a few different meaning but none of them makes the sense in the context to me.

Comment: I've never come across the phrase "what to hell".  It's most likely a typo for "what the hell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **hold someone|something up** is to delay them|it.

> We didn't get to the wedding on time. We were held up by an accident
>   that closed the bridge for two hours.
>
> You will spoil the surprise party if you don't get here soon. What's holding you up?
>
> The unavailability of a critical component held up production of the new phone.

So the person is the automobile is asking impatiently, "Why are you making us wait here?"

Comment: Thank you. But the sentence is the reported speech within the reported speech. It would make sense ‘What to hell you were holding me up for – in the meaning how dare you delay me.

Comment: What to hell **was I** holding him up for?  But that wasn't the question you asked.

Comment: Have you presented the text "as is" or is this your punctuation?

Comment: Yes, I have the original. So I cited accurately.

Comment: There shouldn't be quotation marks around *What to hell....for*

Comment: With the quotation marks around the *What to hell* question, it seems the author wants to convey the idea that the speaker is relaying the question more-or-less verbatim, and is trying to reflect the register and tone in which it was asked of him.  It is somewhere between indirect paraphrased speech and a direct quote.